# Retrieving content or modification of a deleted or merged branch

Tags: git, patch, branching-and-merging

Say some development has been made on a branch, a pull request has been created, approved and merged in Master, and that branch has been deleted.

Is it possible to retrieve the modifications made in this branch, like extracting a patch? Or is it possible to resurect the branch to access its content? Or is there a workaround we could implement with a tag?

Comment: Do you know the SHA of the merge commit?  If so then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the hash of any of the commits in that branch, preferably the most recent commit, then you can resurrect the branch up to the point of the hash that you remember.  Try doing:

```
git checkout <hash> -b lost_branch
```

However, this will only work from within a repository that actually contained the deleted branch at some point.  You will need to shell into that server somehow.

If the remote git repository is hosted on github, you can navigate to the url:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/commit/<hash>
```

From here, you can use github's web UI to create a PR to merge the lost history into a new branch (or the master branch)

Answer (score 1):

If the branch has been deleted, but was merged to master then you can recover it without having to resort to logging on to other machines.

```
git log --grep 'find some identifying text such as an issue number' master
```

If you do not know the text of a commit message, but you know the old branch name (assuming it was merged using the default setting)

```
git log --grep 'branchname' master
```

Either of the will return the commits affected, and you can recreate the branch by doing

```
git checkout -b branchname oldSHA1*
```

- For the case when you are grepping for the merge commit, you will want oldSHA1^2

If all else fails, try searching for commits that affected files that you know were changed by the missing branch. (Use files that are not commonly modified by other branches, if possible.)

```
git log master -- path/to/file
```